# the relation betwin monotonic, bounded functions and constant functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $ f$ be a non-decreasing function and left continous. and $g$ a non-increasing function and right continous such that\

their exist $ k\in ]0,1[$ such that $f(t)=f(kt) \text{ and } g(t)=g(kt) \text{ for all } t>0$
$$ f(t)+g(t)\leq 1 \quad \text{ for all} \; t>0$$
$$ f(0)=0$$
$$ g(0)=1$$
$$ f,g: \mathbb{R}_+  \rightarrow [0,1]$$
then $ f(t)=1$  and $ g(t)=0$ for all $t>0$.\
this is the last step of my proof i can't find the result. I absurdly assume that f is different from 1, but I fail

Comment: @ElliotYu Modified

Comment: Did you mean $f(t) = 0$ and $g(t) = 1$ instead?

Comment: @user6247850 no

Comment: May I ask why not?  Those certainly satisfy all of your conditions, while the $f$ you propose is not left continuous.

Answer (score 1):

First we will show $g(t) = 1$ for all $t > 0$.  Note that $k^n t \downarrow 0$ for all $t > 0$, so by the right continuity of $g$ we have $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} g(k^n t) = g(0) = 1$.  By the fact that $g(kt) = g(t)$, this implies $1 =  \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} g(k^nt) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} g(t) = g(t).$

Now the fact that $f(t) + g(t) \le 1$ and the fact that $g(t) = 1$ implies $f(t) \le 0$ for all $t > 0$.  But since $f(0) = 0$ and $f$ is non-decreasing, this implies $f(t) = 0$ for all $t$.